# Twitter API: Can one identify which user registered an "impression" with a particular tweet?

Tags: api, twitter, impressions

I know that Twitter's analytics API tallies "impressions" for a particular tweet, but is there a way to find out more information about "impressions", such as the user who registered them and their timestamp?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745).